# É possível sobrecarregar operadores matemáticos do JavaScript para objetos?

Tags: javascript, operadores, sobrecarga

Eu queria saber como podemos sobrecarregar o operador de subtração, para que quando o objeto for subtraído por um outro objeto igual, retorne um novo objeto, com tudo subtraído

Exemplo:

```js
var player = new Vector2(10, 10);
var mass = new Vector2(50, 50);

console.log(player - mass);

/*
Saída: Vector2 { X: -40, Y: -40 }
*/
```

Comment: Não dá, infelizmente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Sobrecarga de operadores existe em JavaScript?

O que a pergunta pede não existe em JavaScript. Chama-se [*operator overloading*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading), ou, em português, sobrecarga de operadores.

O comportamento dos operadores do JavaScript é fixo a um conjunto de tipos, não havendo nenhuma possibilidade de extensão.

Até o momento, operadores aritméticos binários, tais como `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` *sempre* avaliarão a um valor numérico. É até possível customizar como um valor arbitrário utilizado como *operando* é convertido para o primitivo `number`, mas nada pode ser feito para fazer com que o operador resulte em um valor diferente de `number`.

Um exemplo maluco que modifica o processo de conversão ao tipo `number` utilizando [`Symbol.toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive):

```js
class Vector2 {
  constructor(x, y) {
    Object.assign(this, { x, y });
  }
  
  // Modificamos a forma como objetos `Vector2` tornam-se primitivos
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    switch (hint) {
      case 'number':
        return Math.hypot(this.x, this.y);
      default:
        return `Vector2(${this.x}, ${this.y})`
    }
  }
}

const v1 = new Vector2(3, 4);
const v2 = new Vector2(6, 8);

// Convertendo para string:
console.log(`${v1}; ${v2}`);

// Conversão para primitivo `number` é feita implicitamente pelo `-`.
// v2 é convertido para 10; v1 é convertido para 5.
console.log(v2 - v1);
```

Resumindo: não tem como fazer a sobrecarga. Até existe [proposta](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-operator-overloading) para que isso um dia faça parte da linguagem, mas ainda está longe de se tornar realidade.

## Alternativas

Como não é possível modificar o comportamento dos operadores da linguagem, uma solução possível é criar funções que encapsulam a lógica análoga ao operador para um tipo arbitrário.

No caso de vetores bidimensionais, você poderia implementar funções como `vec2_add`, `vec2_mult`, etc. [Isso já foi demonstrado na outra resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/521667/69296)

Uma outra alternativa é definir os métodos correspondentes aos operadores na própria classe. Ao invés de `+`, pode-se ter um método `add` na própria classe. Assim:

```js
class Vector2 {
  constructor(x, y) {
    Object.assign(this, { x, y });
  }
  
  add(other) {
    return new Vector2(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
  }
}

const v1 = new Vector2(1, 2);
const v2 = new Vector2(5, 6);
const v3 = v1.add(v2);
console.log(v3); // { x: 6, y: 8 }
```

A vantagem dessa abordagem é que múltiplas chamadas podem ser encadeadas.

Claro que não fica tão bonito quanto usar o `+`, mas é o que eu vejo como mais expressivo no JavaScript atual.

Answer (score 4):

A forma como você demonstrou (`player - mass`) vai lhe retornar `NaN` como resposta, pois o `-` força a conversão para número, o que não é possível com objetos.

Se ambos os objetos são "iguais" em estrutura, o mais simples para o caso é criar uma função que recebe os 2 objetos que terão suas propriedades equivalentes subtraídas para chegar ao resultado esperado `Saída: Vector2 { X: -40, Y: -40 }`.

Criando uma função que recebe estes 2 objetos "iguais", você pode simplismente retornar um objeto com os valores equivalentes de `x` e `y` subtraídos:

```js
class Vector2 {
 constructor(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y
 }
}

var player = new Vector2(10, 10);
var mass = new Vector2(50, 50);

function subtrairVector2 (player, mass) {
  // este if verifica se os objetos são instância de 'Vector2',
  // caso contrário, esta operacao irá ocasionar erros
  if (!(mass instanceof Vector2) || !(player instanceof Vector2)) {
    throw new Error('Not instance of Vector2 class')
  }
  
  return {
    x: player['x'] - mass['x'],
    y: player['y'] - mass['y'],
  }
}

console.log(subtrairVector2(player, mass));
```

Você pode também retornar um novo `Vector2`, alterando a função `subtrairVector2` para que esta retorne uma nova instância dessa classe:

```js
class Vector2 {
 constructor(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y
 }
}

var player = new Vector2(10, 10);
var mass = new Vector2(50, 50);

function subtrairVector2 (player, mass) {
  // este if verifica se os objetos são instância de 'Vector2',
  // caso contrário, esta operacao irá ocasionar erros
  if (!(mass instanceof Vector2) || !(player instanceof Vector2)) {
    throw new Error('Not instance of Vector2 class')
  }
  
  // novos valores para 'x' e 'y'
  const x = player['x'] - mass['x']
  const y = player['y'] - mass['y']
  
  // cria e retorna uma nova instância de Vector2
  return new Vector2(x, y)
}

console.log(subtrairVector2(player, mass));
```

Comment: Só uma sugestão: utilize `TypeError` ao invés de `Error` para notificar que o erro decorre-se de parâmetros com o tipo errado.

Comment: Não é dessa forma, seria algo como Lua, em Lua você pode definir algo que se chama metatable, e nesse metatable da tabela(objeto) você consegue definir funções como: __sub, __div, __mul, __add. e nessas funções você recebe o parâmetro a e o b, que são a, a tabela em questão, e b, o outro argumento, e você pode retornar a soma por lá, usando return a.X - b.X;

Comment: Então com isso é possível fazer algo desse tipo:
```l
local Position = Vector2.new(10, 10)
local Target = Vector2.new(50, 50)

print(Position - Target)
```